# Laravel Model::create() only filling timestamps

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model that Im trying to create.

```
Sale::create([
   'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
   'tenant_id'=>Auth::user()->tenant_id,
   'price'=>$price
]);
```

This creates the record just fine.  Except all it fills in is the created_at, updated_at, and id fields.  It ignores the fields Ive chosen here.

Even though fillable is set

```
   $fillable = ['user_id','tenant_id','app_id','price','other_fields etc etc']
```

Whats up here?? Why is the record only inserting those 3 values and nothing else???

Also if I just do

```
      $sale = New Sale;
      $sale->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
      $sale->tenant_id = Auth::user()->tenant_id;
      $sale->price = $price;
      $sale->save();
```

It works just fine and enters the complete record.

For now, Im leaving it like that, cuz it works....but Id like to figure out why the Model::create() isnt working.  Cuz I really would like to keep my programming consistent as Im using Model::create() basically everywhere else in my App where I create a new record.

**EDIT** - been asked to post the Sale Model

```
  namespace App;
  use Auth;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Sale extends Model
   {

     public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
     {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->connection = env("DB_POOL_1_CONNECTION");
        $this->table = "sales";
     }

     // ******** INPUT VALIDATION ************* //
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     * @var array
     */
     protected $fillable =['tenant_id','rep_id''lead_id','invoice_id','total_price','net_price','tax'];
     protected $hidden = [];
     protected $guarded = [];
```

Ive also posted my File model which works fine, and its identical

```
namespace App;
  use Auth;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class UserFile extends Model
   {

     public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
     {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->connection = env("DB_POOL_1_CONNECTION");
        $this->table = "user_files";
     }

     // ******** INPUT VALIDATION ************* //
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     * @var array
     */
     protected $fillable =['tenant_id','user_id''filename','description','file_size', 'file_path'];

     protected $hidden = [];
     protected $guarded = [];
```

ONLY the Sale Model doesnt insert on Model::create().

The UserFile model does.  And so do my other 28 models, which all share this exact same template, just different tables obviously.

Comment: Is `$fillable` protected? `protected $fillable = ['user_id','tenant_id','app_id','price', ...]`

Comment: Yes it is, but its protected on all my other models, and they work just fine.

Comment: Does `Sale` have a constructor, and if so, does it call `parent::__construct($attributes);`?

Comment: All my models are identical copies of each other.  they all have parent::__construct()  , and protected $fillable.   All the other models work, just not this one

Comment: DigitalDrifter - its posted

Comment: Are you using custom accessors/mutators on your models?

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't use `env('something')` outside of your config files as the environment file will not be loaded after you cached the config with `php artisan config:cache`. Instead, create a config that contains the environment variable and access the config in your code (see database connection in your models).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `>` in `user_id` and `tenant_id`

```
Sale::create([
   'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
   'tenant_id' => Auth::user()->tenant_id,
   'price' => $price
]);
```

Try if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the arrows properly:

```
Sale::create([
   'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
   'tenant_id' => Auth::user()->tenant_id,
   'price' => $price
]);
```

Comment: Thats not it, that was just a typo on stackoverflow, my bad, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I think i saw your problem in github. Seems like a bug in laravel when there is a foreign_key constraint is included in the create method it won't insert that record it seems.

I believe your `tenant_id` is a foreign key here

[github link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12110)